# Why was my edit rejected again?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I'd like to know why [my original edit](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/110992) was rejected again, even though I asked to give some time to the user who posted it to review it.

Was there anything "factually wrong" in my edit?

It added a link, formatted, and expanded a few sentences. I don't understand why it was rejected, and I don't understand why my request that the user who posted the answer for which I suggested an edit should review it was denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was rejected because the users who reviewed the suggested edit thought it was changing the meaning of the answer.

Effectively, the suggested edit added that Drush 9 is Composer-centralized, while it's simply suggested not to install Drush 9 globally (which is possible also with Composer).
It also introduce a grammar error, in the following sentence. (Emphasis on the wrongly changed part is mine.)

> A composer based Drupal project **is installed** by `composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project` includes Drush 9 locally by default and [this is the only recommend way to use Drush 9](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project).

The correct sentence is the original one.

> A composer based Drupal **installed** by `composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project` includes Drush 9 locally by default and this is the only recommend way to use Drush 9, see https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project.

Inlining a link, or editing it to show its title is fine; rewriting a sentence to make it clearer is fine, but adding a sentence the poster didn't put (and containing a not correct assertion) isn't fine.

Answer (score 3):

I just rejected your 2nd attempt about the edit you suggested. I did so with reason ***attempt to reply***, of which these are some details of it:

> It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

If you really want to get ***your*** corrections/additions included, then I strongly recommend you to post an ***additional*** answer in which you mention how it complements and/or corrects the existing answer. It is that easy ... As a bonus, your answer may even get upvoted ...

Answer (score 2):

You edited an answer to your own question. You added new text passages and changed others. If you need something to be clarified, please ask for it in the comments.

Given answers are there to help all future readers who have a similar problem. If you find that all given answers don't match 100% your needs, feel free to add and accept your own answer.